# Bitwise Comparison and Converting C to Delphi

Tags: c, delphi

I have the following C code:

```
pIBM [unsigned char *, a function parameter, for input]
pIEEE [unsigned char *, a function parameter, for output] 

char tmp[8];

memcpy(tmp, pIBM, 8);
memset(pIEEE, 0, 8);

if (*tmp && memcmp(tmp+1, pIEEE, 7) == 0)
{
   pIEEE[0] = pIEEE[1] = 0xff;
   pIEEE[2] = ~(*tmp);

   return;
}
```

1. How does `if (*tmp && memcmp(tmp+1, pIEEE, 7) == 0)` work?
2. How to convert the C code to Delphi, literal and/or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (*tmp && memcmp(tmp+1, pIEEE, 7) == 0)
```

Here `tmp` is an array that decays to a pointer. So `*tmp` is true when `tmp[0]` is not equal to zero. And the `memcmp` test returns true when the final 7 elements of the array match the contents of `pIEEE`. And `pIEEE` is initialized to contain zeros. I guess you know that `&&` is the logical AND operator.

If I were writing this in Delphi it would look something like this:

```
type
  TMyData = array [0..7] of Byte;

function Foo(const IBM: TMyData): TMyData;
begin
  FillChar(Result, 8, 0);
  if (IBM[0]<>0) and CompareMem(@IBM[1], @Result[0], 7) then
  begin
    Result[0] := $ff;
    Result[1] := $ff;
    Result[2] := not IBM[0];
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

To 1:

```
if (*tmp && memcmp(tmp+1, pIEEE, 7) == 0)
```

is equivalent to (but not proper Delphi yet):

```
if (tmp^ <> 0) and (memcmp(tmp + 1, pIEEE, 7) = 0) then
```

Of course that is not proper Delphi (because arrays and pointers can not be treated the same way, in Delphi, and `memcmp` is not part of core Delphi), so try this:

```
if (tmp[0] <> 0) and CompareMem(@tmp[1], @pIEEE[0], 7) then
```

To 2:

```
var
  tmp: array[0..7] of Byte;
begin
  Move(pIBM[0], tmp[0], SizeOf(tmp));
  FillChar(pIEEE, 8, 0);
  if (tmp[0] <> 0) and CompareMem(@tmp[1], @pIEEE[0], 7) then
  begin
    pIEEE[0] := $FF;
    pIEEE[0] := $FF;
    pIEEE[2] := not tmp[0];
    Exit;
  end;
end;
```

That is more or less a "literal" translation. I guess you can see how it can be improved a little (by avoiding `tmp` and reading from `pIBM` directly).

Comment: Your Delphi code helpful. I do prefer CopyMemory over Move (little confusing since it is not actually moving).

Comment: @Mike Move is idiomatic Delphi and portable. Rudy also makes explicit the point that the copy is needless and can be removed.

Comment: The question is what is the purpose of the code? Judging by the names used it is floating point data format conversion but as such it makes absolutely no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (*tmp && memcmp(tmp+1, pIEEE, 7) == 0)
```

is the same as

```
if ((0 != tmp[0]) && (memcmp(&tmp[1], &pIEEE[0], 7) == 0))
```

So this is two tests:

1. Doesn't `tmp[0]` contain `\0'`?
2. Are the seven `char`s `tmp[1] .. tmp[7]` equal to the seven chars `pEEE[0] .. pEEE[6]`?

---

> How to convert the C code to Delphi, literal and/or otherwise?

1. Read the C code
2. Understand what you read
3. Write the corresponding Delphi code

Comment: Your explanation helpful.

Answer (score 0):

would be something as follows (sorry if my Pascal skills are a bit rusty)
For Q1:

The condition 
  if (*tmp && memcmp(tmp+1, pIEEE, 7) == 0)
can be read as

if first char pointer by tmp (*tmp == tmp[0]) is not zero (!= '\0'), then compare the tmp array starting 2nd char with pIEEE array (up to seven chars), if that comparison is equal, then execute

pIEEE[0] = pIEEE[1] = 0xff;

pIEEE[2] = ~(*tmp);

As for Q2:
Could be something like

pIBM [PChar, a function parameter, for input]
pIEEE [PChar, a function parameter, for output]

```
var tmp, tmp2 : PChar;

var flag : SizeInt;

StrLCopy(tmp, pIBM, 8);

pIEEE[0] := #0;
```

pIEEE[1] := #0;

pIEEE[2] := #0;

```
pIEEE[3] := #0;

pIEEE[4] := #0;

pIEEE[5] := #0;

pIEEE[6] := #0;

pIEEE[7] := #0;

if ^tmp <> #0 then

begin

   Tmp2 := Tmp;

   Inc(Tmp2);

   Flag := StrLComp(Tmp2, pIEEE, 7);

   if Flag = 0 then

   begin

       pIEEE[0] = #ff;

       pIEEE[1] = #ff;

       pIEEE[2] = not tmp[0];

   end

end;
```

NOTE: PChar is the type equivalent to Null terminated strings in C, see the unit Strings.pas (or in FreePascal http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/pcharfunctions.html)